# How to replace the ObjectId ref. with with the actual object from MongoDB (idealy on the server side)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express, mongoose

Here is the schema of the principal object:

```
var newsSchema = new Schema({
    headline: String,
    paragraph: String,
    imgURI: String,
    imgThumbURI: String,
    imgCaption: String,
    addedOn: Date,
    addedBy: {
        type: ObjectID,
        ref: 'usr'
    }
});
var News = mongoose.model('news', newsSchema);
```

...and the schema for the addedBy:

```
var usr = new Schema({
    username: String,
    avatar: {
        type: ObjectID,
        ref: 'avtr'
    },
    href: String
});
var UserModel = mongoose.model('usr', usr);
```

So far so good. All works. Then in Angular client I retrieve a news object, but the addedBy value is not the desired object, but an ObjectId:

```
{
    "headline":"Shocking news from the Neverland!",
    ...
    "addedBy":"520e9aac9ca114914c000003", // <-- the offender!!
    "addedOn":"2013-08-16T21:33:32.294Z",
    "_id":"520e9aac9ca114914c000001",
    "__v":0
}
```

When I want an object like this:

```
{
    "headline":"Shocking news from the Neverland!",
    ...
    "addedBy":{
        "username":"Peter"
        "avatar":{
            "src":"../images/users/avatars/avatar1.png", 
            "ststus":"happy"}
        }
    "addedOn":"2013-08-16T21:33:32.294Z",
    "_id":"520e9aac9ca114914c000001",
    "__v":0
}
```

So yes, I want to all (no mater how deeply) nested ObjectId's be replaced with their respective objects from the DB, before the principal object is sent to the angular client. The API I am building is deep and complex and it would be nice if the angular client could to receive from my Express server an object which is ready to be thrown into a scope.
How do I change the following '/news' route:

```
app.get('/news', function(req, res, next){
    News.
        find().
        exec(function(err, nws){
            if(err) {res.writeHead(500, err.message)}
            res.send(nws);
        });
});
```

to accomplish just that, so I can fully access the complete (nested) object from angular like this:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngResource'])
    .controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $resource){
        var News = $resource('/news');
        var news = News.query();
        $scope.news = news;
    });
```

and then on the website access the api like this:

```
<img class="avatar-img" src="{{ news[0].addedBy.avatar.src }}">
```

I very much appreciate your time,
cheers
Jared

Comment: You need to use `populate` to fill in properties. They don't get resolved on the server and instead require one or more additional queries to populate the documents. So, your schema's may not be efficient to fill.

Comment: Just a note, if you continue with this schema it's likely that you'll be continually fighting with MongoDB.  Especially if your objects live in different collections.  Doing lots of `join`s with `ObjectID`s is not the proper way to maximize the benefits of MongoDB.

Comment: @Mason So what is the proper way of oding lots of joins in MongoDB?

Comment: Generally you don't want to do joins in MongoDB - you want to embed documents wherever possible.  Denormalization is the name of the game in MongoDB and it's where a lot of the speed up & scalability over traditional RDBMSes comes from.  Tools like Mongoose will allow you to do joins in the application layer but you should be aware of the fact that under the hood it's performing multiple queries and is likely less efficient than a typical RDBMS join

Comment: @Mason Ok, but to embed a document in a client-side app I first do need to query for it. In other words, in the end I still need to make queries for all the data (i.e. documents) the app requires. The only difference I can see between embedding a number of documents and making joins of these is that I access the documents from across a number of collections. Does accessing a number of collections have the performance impact you mentioned? Or do I misunderstand the difference between those two ways of accessing the data from MongoDB altogether?

Comment: When I talk about embedding documents I'm talking about within MongoDB.  Instead of joining two data structures together you put one inside of the other.  By doing that you can bring back all the info you need in a single query instead of querying the database multiple times (which then requires a join within your application layer).  See the difference between embedding and referencing here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @WiredPrairie said, you need to use the populate function [Populate Mongoose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Your query should look like this:

```
app.get('/news', function(req, res, next){
    News.
        find().
        populate("addedBy").
        exec(function(err, nws){
            if(err) {res.writeHead(500, err.message)}
            res.send(nws);
        });
});
```

There are plenty of different things that you can do with populate, for example to bring only the username field of the "addedBy" document, you can do

```
populate("addedBy","username")
```

or if you don't want bring one specific field, doing something like this:

```
populate("addedBy","-username")
```

Comment: Thank you. This does populate the 'addedBy', but not the 'avatar that's within the 'addedBy'. I am getting a message: 'code { message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "admin" at path "last"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'admin',
  path: 'last' }
undefined'

Comment: Well, as @Mason suggest, you should give a quick look to the noSQL documentation (hope this help http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/09/JOINs-via-denormalization-for-NoSQL-coders-Part-1-Intro) , I been there and it is really hard to avoid the idea of normalization, but to use the power of a db like Mongo, denormalization is the way to go, In this case, the avatar as a document by itself doesn't look like it is need it. With an small tweak to your Document Schema should be fine. What do you think about make the avatar url as part of the user document? Cheers